# How to add any language keyboard in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, keyboard

How to add any language keyboard in Ubuntu 16.04 ?

Answer (score 6):

In `Language Support` you can change the display language. The place to change the keyboard is: `System Settings -> Text Entry`.